# iOS compatibility issues with MAC OS

Tags: iphone, ios, macos

I recently upgraded iPhone 4 device to iOS 7.0. Now we plan to upgrade our development system, MAC OS 10.7.5 to 10.8.5 and use Xcode 5.

I have the following questions:

1. Will i be able to test my app using iPhone 4?
2. Do i need to test it on a newer hardware device like iPhone5?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, iOS7 is compatible with iPhones:4,4s,5,5c,5s.....  as long as you've iOS7 in your device you will be able to test new applications there.
2. It depends: for features that are not allowed on 4 and 4s you will need a 5 but for features that are allowed in the 4 you will not need to test on the 5,

In general, as long as it works in 4 it (might)also work on 5...but that's not necesary true the other way around...

Answer (score 1):

The answer on first question is YES, and to the second one - NO.

You have to upgrade to `XCode 5` to test on `iOS 7` devices.

And if you plan supporting apps on iPhone 4, then please don't test them on newer devices, spend most of your time testing on the older devices like iPhone 4. I have omitted this once and have been regretting it ever since.

Answer (score 1):

1.You can test the iOS7 on devices starting from iPhone4 after updating.

2.You really don't need to have iPhone5 for testing iOS7 because you already have iOS7 on iPhone4. For Testing on multiple devices try to optimize your app for different devices and You could use the iOS simulators to test the app always.